# Defining a mixed array of tuples

Tags: typescript

I have a function I'm trying to convert to typescript. It deals with an Array of mixed type tuples similar to `Promise.all`. I can't figure out how to setup the definitions for the function.

```
export type Type<T> = [T, boolean];

function fn<T1, T2>(list: [Type<T1>, Type<T2>]): [T1, T2] {
    return list.map(([value]) => value);
}

fn([
    ['string', true],
    [123, false],
    // Probably more
]);
// [ 'string', 123 ]
```

`Promise.all` defines ten different options like:

```
all<T1, T2, T3>(values: readonly [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3]>;
all<T1, T2>(values: readonly [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>]): Promise<[T1, T2]>;
all<T>(values: readonly (T | PromiseLike<T>)[]): Promise<T[]>;
```

Do we have a better way in typescript than explicitly listing all the possible lengths of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to make the `list` parameter a [mapped array/tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) type; if the desired output of the function is some array/tuple type `T`, then `list` is what you get when you iterate over each numeric index `I` of `T` and change the element from `T[I]` to `Type<T[I]>`.  Then the compiler can use [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) to compute `T` from the type of `list`.

Here's one possible implementation:

```
export type Type<T> = readonly [T, boolean];

function fn<T extends readonly any[]>(
  list: readonly [...{ [I in keyof T]: Type<T[I]> }]
): T {
    return list.map(([value]) => value) as any;
}
```

Of note:

- I've made all array types `readonly` because this is less restrictive than mutable arrays.  Mutable array types are assignable to read-only array types, but not vice-versa.  Nothing in the example code leads me to believe you actually want to *prohibit* read-only inputs, and certain language features like [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) produce them, so you'll probably be happier this way.
- The `list` parameter is of a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) `[...XXX]` instead of just `XXX`; this gives the compiler a hint that it should be interpreting `list` as a tuple and not an unordered array.  Otherwise you'd lose the ordering, and the output of `fn()` would tend to be something like `Array<string | number>` instead of the `[string, number]` or `["string", 123]` you're looking for.
- I have used a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to `any` in the implementation of `fn()`.  While you could possibly avoid `any` and use something less unsafe, you will never get full type safety here; the compiler does not understand that `list`'s `map()` method will behave as the call signature requires.  The TS library typing for `map()` returns an unordered array type: it would infer that you're outputting a value of type `T[number][]` (an unordered array of the elements of `T`).  We have to use a type assertion or other similar loosening to tell the compiler that it's okay if it can't verify that the output will be of type `T`, and that *we* are taking on the responsibility for verifying type safety.  This means we should be careful that the implementation is correct, because the compiler will not notice if we get it wrong.

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
const result = fn([
    ['string', true],
    [123, false],
    [new Date(), true]
]);
// const result: [string, number, Date]
```

Okay, the compiler sees that the output is of type `[string, number, Date]`.  If that's sufficient, great.  If you wanted to see [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) or [numeric literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#numeric-literal-types) types instead, you could use a `const` assertion:

```
const resultNarrower = fn([
    ['string', true],
    [123, false],
    [new Date(), true]
] as const);
// const resultNarrower: ["string", 123, Date]
```

This is accepted because of the `readonly` changes above.  The output type is now `["string", 123, Date]`.  Hooray!

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqzgB40D44C8cUwAhgCYQB2ANonANpoA0cARhBDWVQLoDcAKEEAzAK5UAxjACW1OCKo44oGMCrkAzsTKVa9UlUQNeuABQ0ZmmAC4dFanUYA6VwG9GASTgyqcANbAiBAi6Lx2GCg4DJ6mcAC+vACUEXBugnCZOjBiUH6W1s4AtqRgZmYMAG6kNGLAyYT41bXASXCk2oaIQvHCktTWOppiNPBEihUZWQwA5NZQvgDmM6wwUHW8zFOZDACMAEwAzKwiNZr1W1mMVMAA7nAAIqRqZkmr6-WCyUIA9D9w-SogxIw1GdgY8yWrCoYiKbGAUFYTzUvD6A3gIJGMAAcqQoFAILcEYQFFRJldZpCqMt3htLtMDscFGcLttrndHs9gK9aZ9eO1tIDrElfv8hRjgKCcXiCUSoOCAERUxYK1iMpFc1FAA)

Comment: `[...{ [I in keyof T]: Type<T[I]> }]` is absolute sorcery and I'll need a moment for my brain to refactor over that

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in next solution:

```js
type Fst<T> = T extends readonly [infer A, infer B] ? A : never;
type MapPredicate<T> = Fst<T>

type Mapped<
    Arr extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>,
    Result extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> = readonly []
    > = Arr extends readonly []
    ? readonly [1]
    : Arr extends readonly [infer H]
    ? readonly [...Result, MapPredicate<H>]
    : Arr extends readonly [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? Mapped<readonly [...Tail], readonly [...Result, MapPredicate<Head>]>
    : Readonly<Result>;

type Result = Mapped<[['str', true], [123, true]]>; // ["str", 123]


export type Type<T> = readonly [T, boolean];

function fn<T extends ReadonlyArray<readonly [unknown, boolean]>>(list: T) {
    // no way to avoid type casting here
    return list.map(([value]) => value) as unknown as Mapped<T>
}

const arr = [
    ['string', true],
    [123, false],
    // Probably more
] as const;

const result = fn(arr); // readonly ["string", 123]
```